# Is there any way to chroot a linux filemanager?

Tags: linux, chroot

Just wondering for an idea if it would be possible for a filemanager like xfe, rox, nautilus to be able to run (at launch) with chroot aka not being able to go down the tree.

I would be interested if anyone has an idea on how to do so; it's for a cybercoffe where I don't want people to access other directories.

(solution except using linux fs permission).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file manager will need to see and access of the special files you are trying to hide (such as /proc content and /dev content) in order to work properly.

So yes, you can run a file manager in a chroot, but you need to put (a minimal version of) /dev/ and /proc in the chroot for it to work.

I would either hack the source of the file manager to hide what you want or go all the way and run the file manager in a virtual machine so no damage can be done by end user to real computing resources. qemu/kvm is excellent for that.

Comment: Yeah right; but for this project I don't want to take the high road of virtualisation; i was thinking of some 'out of the box' kind of Kiosk application that linux provides; unfortunately haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using permissions? Generate a temp user on login, give them write access only to their homedir. Anyone who would try to hack your system is not going to have trouble getting around whatever roadblocks you have in place. THey'd probably start by firing up an xterm anyway. Besides, security through obscurity isn't.

Comment: Yeah, but i (ideally) want them not be able to see all the fancy dirs like /dev/ /sys/ /ect, just their home folder, nothing else. I'm aware that it's an akward question.